# Changing checkbox icon with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, simple-form

I'm new at rails and web apps and I would appreciate if someone could help with this.
Using simple_form and trying to change checkbox icon image but css(scss) seems not working.
Codes are below.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <%= f.input :is_something, as: :boolean, input_html: { class: 'custom-check-box' } %>
</div>
```

Generated Code

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="input boolean optional test_is_somethiing"><input value="0" type="hidden" name="test[is_something]" /><label class="boolean optional checkbox" for="test_is_somethiing"><input class="boolean optional custom-check-box" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="test[is_something]" id="test_is_somethiing" />Label</label></div>
</div>
```

And SCSS is

```
.custom-check-box {
   opacity: 0;
   vertical-align: middle;
   input[type=checkbox] + label:after {
     opacity: 1;
     display: inline-block;
     background: image-url('check_box_off.png');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     vertical-align: middle;
     background-size: 50%;
     cursor: pointer;
     &:checked + label:after {
       opacity: 1;
       display: inline-block;
       background-size: 50%;
       background: image-url('check_box_on.png');
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       vertical-align: middle;
       cursor: pointer;
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing a few things to get this working.

In your HTML you need to have a `<label>` tag with a `for=""` attr, like so;

```
<div>
  <input id="custom-checkbox" class="custom-check-box" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="custom-checkbox"></label>
</div>
```

The labels for attr needs to match the checkbox's id

Then for your scss change `input[type=checkbox] + label:after` to `& + label:after`, like so;

```
.custom-check-box {
   display: none;
   vertical-align: middle;

   & + label:after {
     content: '';
     padding: 16px;
     display: inline-block;
     background: image-url('check_box_off.png');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     vertical-align: middle;
     background-size: 50%;
     cursor: pointer; 
   }

   &:checked + label:after {
     background: image-url('check_box_on.png');
   }

 }
```

Your `:after` pseudos also require a content attr for them to work.

[I created a codepen for you](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oLobBA)

Comment: thank you. I checked generated code and it has "for" attributes. and tried your code but still same...

Comment: Yeah looking at your generated html you need the label to come AFTER the checkbox. There is no way in pure SCSS (yet) to target a previous element.